# Splitting an Android project?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

Is it possible to split an Android project so I can like create a "module", or similar, with one environment e.g. Eclipse and using another environment to do everything else e.g. Android Studio? And to make them communicate with eachother or converting everything to Eclipse would take less time to develop?

I've created a project in Android Studio and now after alot of work I found out I need to convert to Eclipse as Android Studio does not offer the support it requires for Google API.

Comment: you must be kidding right ? Android studio is the official development tool for android and it does not offer support for Google API ....

Comment: And you can create a module in your project AND you can also open multiple projects in android studio. And you can also import modules in different projects too.

Comment: _""With the release of Android Studio 2.2, the time has now come to say goodbye to the Eclipse Android Developer Tools," product manager Jamal Eason said in a blog post last week. "We have formally ended their support and development."_

Comment: There is absolutely no reason for you to use Eclipse. Google API not working is not a valid reason to move to Eclipse. Instead, you should fix it so it works again in Android Studio.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, but I need something that isn't available, it wasn't when I was working on my project, so I can use Google Adwords API. Otherwise my application serves no purpose.

Here is the dialogue I had with Josh on the Google forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-api/LrbDtYBox9I

Comment: I think you misunderstood him, he never said Android Studio doesn't support adwords.

Comment: I will try to create a service that handles everything regarding Google Adwords and just let the rest of my application be handled and developed using Android Studio. I would really like to stick to one environment as of this moment and this project.

@nasch Oh, I must have missed that part...